# Is there a way to prevent libcaca from displaying blinking text when using ncurses or raw driver?

Tags: ncurses, ascii-art

For some reason almost any image I attempt to display with libcaca has flashing text in some areas. This happens in every terminal I've tested with `CACA_DRIVER=ncurses` as well as using `CACA_DRIVER=raw` in conjunction with `cacaserver` over telnet. It doesn't seem to happen with `CACA_DRIVER=slang` or `CACA_DRIVER=x11` however. Is this an intended feature or a weird incompatibility with something and is there any way to fix/disable it?

Comment: After further testing, I've discovered it works correctly in the Rxvt terminal, but exhibits the weird blinking behavior in Konsole, Xterm, Kitty, Qterminal, Deepin Terminal, and Cool Retro Term

Comment: That sounds like the usual problem from mixing ncurses 5.9 headers with ncurses 6.x libraries (or the reverse, of course).  There's not enough information to use, though.